# Why can we only use radians in the arc length formula?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, rotation

Why can't we use degrees in the arc length formula ($S = R\theta$)? Why only radians?

I don't understand because radians and degrees are both dimensionless.

Comment: This question isn't related with GR and quantum mechanics at all.

Comment: Sorry @DebanjanBiswas, it is fixed now

Comment: This question is about math, not physics.

Comment: *Why can't we use degrees?* Does a circular arc that subtends only 1 degree look to you like it has a length equal to the radius?

Answer (score 1):

I can't totally answer your question and I don't have enough rep to add comment so I have to add it in answer. I guess it is because degrees and radians are defined in different ways. Take a circle and cut it into 360 equal parts and one of the part becomes a degree while radian is defined as ratio of the length of the arc to the radius of the circle that makes the arc.

Comment: Your answer is all right. Just needs some good sentences and a few information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Radian is essentially defined by the formula you mention:

$$\theta = \frac s r$$

Saying an angle is $\frac {\pi}{2}$ radians is saying "the ratio of the length of the arc to the radius of the arc is $\frac {\pi}{2}$" or equivalently, "the length of the arc subtended by an angle $\theta$ in a circle of radius $1$ is $s$." That is why this formula works for radians and only radians.

A degree symbol ° you can view as a constant factor equal to $\frac {\pi}{180}$, which we use because it's easier to think about whole numbers like 120° than irrational numbers like 2.094333.  But it's completely arbitrary and not native to the nature of a circle itself, like the radian definition is. But feel free to use degrees as long as you remember to multiply by that factor when calculating something.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Sorry I cannot upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is the arc of a circle, one way to describe it is what "percentage" of the circle's circumference it represents. So, if you have a quarter circle for example, you can say that its arc length is $2\pi R/4$.

Note that we can describe the "percentage" of a circle using degrees -- we just have to divide by 360.  By that logic, a quarter circle arc length is $2\pi R \times\dfrac{90}{360} = 2\pi R/4$ as before.  If we generalize this for an arbitrary angle $\theta$ in degrees, what you get is that arc length is $$S = 2\pi R \times \dfrac \theta {360}= \dfrac{R\theta}{180}$$

Note that $\theta / 180$ is just the same angle in radians, so, if $\phi$ is an angle measured in radians, the arc length is $S = R\phi$.

You can think of radians as measuring the arc length of the unit circle -- that way, $2\pi$ radians makes up the whole unit circle (since its circumference is $2\pi$). From there, multiplying by the radius $R$ will give us the corresponding arc length for a circle of radius $R$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Sorry I cannot upvote your answer.